# Host port appears closed inside Docker container

Tags: macos, docker, networking, docker-compose, xdebug

## Objective

I'm trying to figure out why I can't access PhpStorm via port 9000 from inside my Docker container.

## Setup

### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y telnet nmap
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    build: .
```

## Steps

- Test port is accessible from host: `telnet 127.0.0.1 9000` (succeeds)
- `docker-compose up`
- `docker container ls`
- `docker exec -it [CONTAINER] /bin/bash`
- Find host IP inside container: `/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }'`
- Ping the IP from inside container: `ping 172.18.0.1` (succeeds)
- Inside container, try connecting to port using host IP: `telnet 172.18.0.1 9000` (fails)
- Inside container, check if port is open using nmap: `nmap 172.19.0.1 -p 9000` (shows port as closed)

Telnet fails with `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

nmap results:

```
# nmap 172.19.0.1 -p 9000

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-07-03 18:43 UTC
Nmap scan report for 172.19.0.1
Host is up (0.000040s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
9000/tcp closed cslistener
MAC Address: [redacted] (Unknown)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.68 seconds
```

## My Question

How do I access port 9000 (used by PhpStorm to listen for Xdebug connections) inside my Docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running Docker on Mac .. and there Docker has some nuances when it comes to the network setup.

Quite likely that the IP address that you have detected (`172.18.0.1`) is not an actual host IP.

It's better if you use special host name `host.docker.internal` (as per official workaround doc article: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#per-container-ip-addressing-is-not-possible )

Comment: What if I can ping service by name but can't connect to port (connection refused)?

Comment: @Kfcaio `ping` uses different protocol and just checks if overall connection can be made. But to be able to connect on some TCP port requires some program/service to actually listen on that port there. Plus, it could be a firewall that denies either outgoing (local one; less likely) or incoming (remote; more likely) connection.